# String to Character Array

Tags: arrays, string, char, java-7

I have a problem with my code below:

```
public class stringToChar {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    char[] sCharArr;
    String[] odd = new String[n];
    String[] even = new String[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sCharArr = in.next().toCharArray();
        for(int j = 0; j < sCharArr.length; j++) {
            if(j % 2 == 0)
                even[i] += sCharArr[j];
            else
                odd[i] += sCharArr[j];
        }
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       System.out.println(even[i] + "  " + odd[i]);
   }
 }
}
```

My issue is on the output it has a `Null` in the result. Here is a sample scenario:

```
2
John
Cena
```

Answer should be:

```
Jh  on
Cn  ea
```

But my code answer is:

```
NullJh  Nullon
NullCn  Nullea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the new arrays are initialized with all **null** Strings. Then your code is **not** assigning values to all array elements, but just to some of them!

Finally you print your array, and surprise, those values that **were** null and that have not been changed - are still null (and when you print a null string ... it prints "null" [ yes, **n**ull, not **N**ull; you got a little mistake there in your output example ]

You see, you iterate from 0 to the length of your **two** arrays. And if the number is even, you put a value in the even[i]; and if the value is odd, it goes to odd[i]. Lets take even - in that case, odd[i] simply stays null!

One way to fix that:

```
List<String> even = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> odd = new ArrayList<>();
```

And now, instead of setting a certain index in even/odd; you simply do:

```
even.add(some new value);
```

and to add those single characters:

```
even.add(new String(sCharArr));
```

Doing so, even and odd will (in the end) contain exactly the values that you **added** to each list; but no "residual" nulls. For the record: the way how you split up strings, to then pull them back into a String array isn't exactly the most simple/straight forward way to solve the problem.

But I leave "further" simplifications" as exercise to the user.

Comment: Thank you!! Very helpful and informative, this is the answer to my issue!

Comment: I tried to add your suggestion, but I cannot add a single character in the List<String> I suppose that it should be a String type to be added. But since I converted the String to charArray how will I be able to add the char on the List<String>?

Comment: GhostCat thank you for the update however it outputs in on a single line mixing John and Cena, and it is enclosed in "[ ]".

Comment: That is because you are probably printing the whole list at once. Tried iterating it; as you did your array?